Can I set QGIS to summarize icons above a certain scale and display only the number of icons in an area?
I would like to know if it is possible to set up a function in QGIS to automatically summarize icons on the map above a certain scale so that only one icon is displayed, representing the number of icons in that area (20+, 30+, etc.).
An example of this: There are many different stops in the city. When I zoom in, I can see each stop in the right place, but when I zoom out, the pins should be grouped together and only one icon should be visible to show how many pins are in the area (e.g. 20, 30, ...). If i zoom out to max, there should be just one pin with the amount of stops in the whole city. Here is an example map of Ljubljana:

The aim is to keep the map clear and still convey important information about the density or number of points without losing the details.

It seem you should investigate the cluster point renderer... https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#point-cluster-renderer

Yes, the symbolization style you are looking for is 'Point cluster'
In the layer styling pane, choose the 'Point cluster' style. See the example below.
The first image is a random assortment of points generated in an extent. [1]
The second image is using the Point Cluster style, which groups points together into a single point and can show the number of points in that group. [2]
As you zoom in, the groups will disperse and show individual points. There are settings you can play with to control how far points have to be from each other to be included in a group.
Hopefully that helps!
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/kErWP7ib.png
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/6HFVqNqB.png

Thank you, that is exactly what i looked for!
